# Check if ajax in the preprocess_node

Tags: theming, 8, ajax

There seems to be a problem when I check if the node is served by ajax or not, I use this function :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $variables['is_ajax'] = true;
    }else{
        $variables['is_ajax'] = false;
    }
}
```

The same code works great with **preprocess_page** or **preprocess_html**

Is there a way to make it work? or eventually get the page/html variable in the node preprocess ?

Thank you !

Comment: maybe just check if current path is system/ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node is cached and this function is only called for the first time the node is displayed for the given view mode.

If you really need to vary your output between ajax and non-ajax context, you need to add a cache context for that. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts and the other related documentation pages. You could use the header:NAME-OF-THE-header cache context I guess.

As an alternative, do whatever needs to be done differently with ajax vs not  with Javascript/CSS